# Как оптимизировать представление google таблицы в виде веб-приложения

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Требуется представить google-таблицу, как веб-страницу с возможностью использовать стили.
Попробовал реализовать так, пример index.html для таблицы 2х2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onSuccess1(Value) {document.getElementById('pow1').innerHTML = Value;}
function onSuccess2(Value) {document.getElementById('pow2').innerHTML = Value;}
function onSuccess11(Value) {document.getElementById('row11').innerHTML = Value;}
function onSuccess12(Value) {document.getElementById('row12').innerHTML = Value;}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess1).returnCellValue('A1');
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess2).returnCellValue('B1');
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess11).returnCellValue('A2');
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess12).returnCellValue('B2');

</script>

<table border="1">

<tr> 
<th>  <div id="pow1"></div>  </th>
<th>  <div id="pow2"></div>  </th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div id="row11"></div> </td>
<td><div id="row12"></div> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

и ниже блок со стилями.
Результат в принципе устраивает, но даже для средней таблицы (5х5) код получается громоздким и есть значимая задержка отображения данных.

Пример: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzl1nEfqH0YdMFbx-IhcDK43vbj4ujIfBjp4xzplxUVaGbz2ng/exec

Как это можно оптимизировать?

Comment: Попробовал реализовать иначе, получилась быстрая выгрузка, но не могу понять, как применить стили. Т.к. реализация отличается и проблема другая задал отдельный вопрос тут:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829676/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел вот такое решение, страница загружается в разы быстрее:

```
function onSuccess(Value) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = toHTMLTable(Value);
    }

    function toHTMLTable(a) {
      var content = a.map(function(row, i) {
        var rowHTML = row.map(function(col) {
          return "<td>" + col + "</td>";
        }).join("");

        return "<tr>" + rowHTML + "</tr>";
      }).join("");
      return "<table>" + content + "</table>";
    }

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnCellValue('A1:C3');
```

Answer (score 1):

Сократить можно, создав функцию, которая будет создавать функции сама. К примеру так:

```
<table border="1">
<tr> 
<th><div id="A1"></div></th>
<th><div id="B1"></div></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="A2"></div></td>
<td><div id="B2"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var cellNames = 'A1,B1,A2,B2'.split(',');

function showCellValue(cellName)
{
    var onSuccess = new Function('Value',
                    'document.getElementById(' + cellName + ').innerHTML = Value');
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnCellValue(cellName);
}

for (var i = 0; i < cellNames.length; i++)
    showCellValue(cellNames[i]);
</script>
```

Id от div-ов лучше назвать также как и в таблице, чтобы не запутаться. Но если нужны разные имена, то добавьте в function showCellValue второй параметр.

Comment: Спасибо. 
Код стал значительно короче.
Но данные отображаются с такой же задержкой, т.к. вызывается тоже кол-во функций (пусть и в цикле).
Отличная идея "Id от div-ов лучше назвать также как и в таблице".